# Rsyncing files from server to local machine automatically

Tags: rsync, find

I currently have a `crontab` job running on my machine every friday at 3 AM as a back up method.  The job runs a bash script which runs an `rsync` command to sync files from the server to my external hard drive.  The rsync command uses the `--include-from` flag to get a list of files to rsync such as `*.cpp *.h` etc.

Unfortunately I'm running out of space on my hard drive and I want to replace it with another drive with the same storage room on it.  If I just continue the rsync as it is, I would not have gained anything because the second drive will be identical to the first, and it'll be full.

I would ideally like to rsync only files from `--include-from` AND newer than the date at which I replaced my external drives (e.g., say I replace my drive today, then I want to rsync the files in my included file list *AND* newer than 3/27/2015).  That way it'll just be a continuation of the first drive.

Everything I can find online uses the `find` method to first get a list of files newer than date, and then pipe that list to `rsync`.  But since this is all happening from my local machine, how can I use `find` from my local machine to get the file list on the server?  Is there a better option, perhaps an `rsync` flag which checks the file's last-modified date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your last backup using the old disk, create a timestamp and then backup files after that timestamp.  You'll use `find` and the `--newer` flag to list files newer than the timestamp, then the `--file-from` flag to `rsync` to specify that list of files for copying.

Here's how:

Step 1:  Before you swap to the new drive: `touch /someplace/timestamp.txt`

Step 2:  Change to the new disk.

Step 3: Modify the cronjob script to do something like:

`find BLAH BLAH BLAH -newer /someplace/timestamp.txt -type f -print0 >/tmp/list
rsync -avP --inplace --file-from=/tmp/list --from0 desthost:/dest/place`

NEVER change, touch, or modify the /someplace/timestamp.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

presumably you have ssh access to the server? so

1. either: grant the server ssh access to your local machine and then use something like `ssh you@server 'find ... | xargs -0 -I {} rsync "{}" you@yourmachine:/media/dir'`
2. or: create a list of files on the server using `find`, then copy this file to your local machine and run rsync from there to grab these files

I have to say I don't like this though. For full file recovery you will still need both of your backup disks, the old one and the new, and the recovery might be complex. I can think of several ways of improving this strategy, but the easiest in your case would be to get a new but *bigger* disk instead of a new one that is the same size. Surely the extra cost is not that significant?